# Permissions to copy denied

Tags: permissions

I am unable to copy onto external device despite going into Dolphin in root.
The permissions are denied and will not change.  I have upgraded in Synaptic also. 
I get this message in root and would be grateful if someone can enlighten me.

```
john@DNUK:~$ sudo dolphin
[sudo] password for john: 
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
kdeinit4: Shutting down running client.
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
kbuildsycoca4 running...
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-john" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
```

John Watt
Ormskirk

Answer (score 2):

There seems to have been a similar question at [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1080625). The two solutions they suggest:

1. Change the owner of the file
2. Run graphical applications as root using gksu / gksudo, or using kdesu in Kubuntu (as opposed to sudo)

Extra: [why you should not run GUI applications with sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo)

Comment: Thanks; I am about to go on hols so I shall have to try these alternative approaches later.